Is this image a good summary of the geometric representation of PLS?
I was wodnering if I could get feedback/criticism on an image I made that seeks to visually explain (in part) what PLS is. Orally I would say that we have three predictor variables ($x_1, x_2, x_3$) and one response variable ($y_1$). I would then proceed to say that PLS seeks to maximize the covariation between the predictors and the response. And to do so we are making random guesses of the first Latent Variable for the predictors (i.e. $LV_1 = x_1 * \beta_1 + x_2 * \beta_2 + x_3 * \beta_3$, where $\beta_n$ is the loading for the n'th predictor), and then projecting it into a new space where we take the scores from $LV_1$ and the response variable (since it is only 1-D the scores are its true values) and plot them.
Mathematically we would simply using the covariance equation for each guess but in a geometric representation we would be plotting them onto a new set of axis (LV scores vs y scores) and storing the error between predicted and true. We then repeat this process by making new guesses of the combination for $LV_1$ and storing the covariance values and ultimately, we will choose the loadings of $LV_1$ that yield the largest covariance value between x and y.
The picture I drew has an example of the x space and the y space on the left hand side, followed by an example of using one instantiation of the $LV_1$ and response values to be plotted, and then are the far right is an example of where the guesses were repeated a number of times and we now have a 'plot' of the covariances to choose from. And we then proceed to select the maximum covariance (denoted by dotted line in the far right graph). 

As the authors of Elements of Statistical Analysis pointed out, tying PLS to conjugate gradient algorithms ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) gave a geometric interpretation. Comparing it to gradient descent, which successively finds orthogonal vectors, conjugate gradient finds successive vectors orthogonal to a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, i.e. the l-th gradient $\mathbf{v_l}$ satisfies
$$
\mathbf{v_l}^T
\mathbf{Av_k} =0 , k = 1,\cdots,l-1
$$
This setup ensures each gradient moves orthogonal to the contour lines of the Mahalabonis distance from the solution (i.e. maximizing covariance shrinkage in every step).
Tying to PLS, Elements of Statistical Learning gives that the m-th PLS direction $\phi_m$ solves
$$
\max_{||\mathbf{a}||=1} Corr^2(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{Xa})Var(\mathbf{Xa})
$$
subject to $\mathbf{\phi_l}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Xa}=0,l=1,\cdots,m-1$. The objective function is equivalent to
$$
Cov^2(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{Xa}) = (\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{Xa})^2
$$
by a constant factor. In terms of conjugate gradient algorithms, PLS seeks covariance-maximizing vectors orthogonal to previous vectors with respect to $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$, a multiple of the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}$. The PLS vectors point sequentially to the PLS-estimate $\hat{\mathbf{y}}_{PLS} = \mathbf{X}\hat{\mathbf{\beta}}_{PLS}$, each orthogonal to the contour line of the Mahalabonis distance from $\hat{\mathbf{y}}_{PLS}$ at the endpoint of the previous vector.
